# Up , Down keyboard interaction not working in custom picklist aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, lightning-combobox

```
    <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" aura:id="resultsDiv" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                        <lightning:input disabled="{!v.disabled}" aura:id="inputLookup" class="inputBox" placeholder="Select an Option" onblur="{!c.blurEvent}" onclick="{!c.showOptions}" onkeyup="{!c.filterOptions}" value="{!v.searchString}" autoComplete="off" variant="label-hidden" id="combobox-id-1" style="{!'width:' + v.Swidth + 'px'}"/>
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-input__icon" iconName="utility:down" size="x-small" alternativeText="search"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Dropdown List -->
                    <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid" style="{! 'max-height:' + (8 + (v.recordCount * 40)) + 'px' }" onkeypress="{!c.callKeyUp}">
                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical recordListBox" role="presentation">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.message)}" >
                                <!-- To display Drop down List -->
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option" >
                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!option.disabled}">
                                        <li class="{!'slds-listbox__item disabledItem' + if(option.isVisible,'',' slds-hide')}">
                                            <span class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity verticalAlign slds-truncate">{!option.label}</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <aura:set attribute="else">
                                            <li id="{!option.value}" class="{!'slds-listbox__item eachItem' + if(option.isVisible,'',' slds-hide')}" onmousedown="{!c.selectItem}">
                                                <lightning:icon class="{!if(option.selected,'','slds-hide')}" iconName="utility:check" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                                                <span class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity verticalAlign slds-truncate">{!option.label}</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </aura:set>
                                    </aura:if>
                                </aura:iteration>
                                <!-- To display Error Message -->
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <li class="slds-listbox__item">
                                        <span class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity verticalAlign slds-truncate">{!v.message}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I observed that the keyboard interaction works when using Lightning:combobox but not in custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Key handling generally requires JavaScript code to be added i.e. HTML/CSS on its own is not sufficient.

You can see this e.g. here [baseCombobox.js](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/83b87d3772557a22de16f74a047a087a51c4934c/force-app/main/default/lwc/baseCombobox/baseCombobox.js#L766) in the [salesforce
/
base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes)
 open source project.

So wherever possible, use implementations of the SLDS components where the hard work of additional functionality such as key handling has already been implemented.